# jMeter really slow reading large CSV results files

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have some performance tests running on some servers and collect metrics (basic enough stuff, CPU and Memory per process)
Anyway CSV file can be large ~20MB (ok not large but large for .csv)

Not a code question here, but jMeter is really slow opening the csv, unusable in fact which is a pity , as it would graph the results for me.

I can open the csv no problem in Excel or other text editors.

Any recommendations for other grapher apps ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate charts in non-GUI mode using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png CPUandRAM.png --input-jtl yourfile.csv --plugin-type PerfMon --width 1024--height 768
```

The Command Line Graph Plotting Tool isn't being shipped with official JMeter distribution, it is an extension, you can install this using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides OOTB an HTML report that can be generated:

- at end of test (-e -o report-folder)
- for an existing CSV (-g csv-file -o report-folder)

It can handle very large CSV files and is very rich.
This is the standard for JMETER reporting.

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report